# C++ variadic template class termination

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Half an hour ago I discovered variadic template parameters and now I am totally hooked.

I have a static class based abstraction for a microcontroller output pin. I want to group a number of output pins so I can handle them as one pin. The code below works, but I think I should be able to end the recursion on 0 parameters instead of on 1.

```
template< typename pin, typename... tail_args >
class tee {
public:

   typedef tee< tail_args... > tail;

   static void set( bool b ){
      pin::set( b );
      tail::set( b );   
   }   

};

template< typename pin >
class tee< pin > {
public:

   static void set( bool b ){
      pin::set( b );
   }   

};
```

I tried this but the compiler (gcc) seems not to take it into account:

```
template<>
class tee<> : public pin_output {
public:

   static void set( bool b ){}   

};
```

The error message is long, but it essentially says that there is no tee<>. Is there something wrong with my tee<> or isn't it possible to end the recursion

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Is it GCC 4.8 and did you pass the `-std=c++11` flag (also with `-Wall`)?

Comment: Your type should be `template <typename ...> class tee`, and your termination case should be `template <> class tee<> { };`.

Comment: @Basile: 4.7.2; I used -std=c++0x; using -std=c++11 -Wall makes no change;

Comment: @Kerrek: when my type is template< typename ...> class tee, how do I identify/use the 'head' of that list?  Edit: after reading Lol4t0's answer I sort of understand what you meant, but I wasn't aware that I should use 2 specializations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your most general case takes at least `1` argument (`pin`), so you cannot create a specialization, that has `0` arguments.

Instead, you should make most general case, that accepts *any* amount of arguments:

```
template< typename... > class tee;
```

And then create specializations:

```
template< typename pin, typename... tail_args >
class tee<pin, tail_args...> {
public:

   typedef tee< tail_args... > tail;

   static void set( bool b ){
      pin::set( b );
      tail::set( b );   
   }   

};

template<>
class tee<> {
public:

   static void set( bool b ){}   

};
```

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm, and I am one small step on my way up :)